# scope variable undefined in directive link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I have a directive which has this piece of code:

```
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        moduleProgress: "=",
        modules: "=",
        parentScroll: "="
    },
    templateUrl: 'app/program/module.list.template.html',
    link: function(scope,el,attrs,ctrl,tf) {
        $templateRequest("app/program/chapter.list.template.html").then(function(template) {
            var template = angular.element(template);
            var elements = [];

            console.log(scope);

            attrs.$observe("modules", function(val) {
                scope.modules.forEach(function(module) {
                    module.open = false;
                });
            });
```

For some reason, the first time I navigate to the view that contains this directive everything works fine, but from the second time onwards I always get a `Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined` error. I read through some similar questions on SO which mentioned interpolated attributes not being instantly available on the link function, so they reccomended the use of `$observe`. I even added a `console.log(scope)` and the `modules` property shows up on the object. Any idea of what might be causing this?

Comment: `scope.modules` is an array. And even if it wasn't a valid method, the problem is that it says my `scope.modules` property is undefined.

Comment: I think you only use `$observe` on attributes (which I'm pretty sure always return strings) that contain interpolation i.e. `{{}}`. So don't think that will work on an array. I might be wrong though. I've never needed to use it.

Comment: Yeah, `$observe` is only for interpolated (@) attributes I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be rather `$scope.$watch` rather that `attrs.$observe` as `$observe` required `@` in isolated scope of directive & on html it would be `modules="{{module}}"`, For big object DOM will get messed up so I'd prefer you to use `$watch` which make sense

**Code**

```
scope.$watch("modules", function(newVal) {
    if(newVal){
        scope.modules.forEach(function(module) {
            module.open = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: That would be a solution. The problem was in my parent controller that defined `$scope.modules` after a promise, so in directive link time it wasn't available yet. I could `$watch` for the property or fetch the data on resolve, which is what I did. But thanks ;)

Comment: @Thiatt updated the answer..yes that if check will validate `modules` value is there or not, Glad to heard that it does helped..Do upvote please..Thanks :)

Comment: After a lifetime of debugging, I finally discovered that promised data was causing my link function to run with undefined values.